# How does razor generator work with .js and .css file types ?

Tags: c#, .net, razor

Razor Generator precompiles .cshtml files then generate .cs files. I wonder, how does it work if I have some javascript files and css files with my view ?

Comment: No .cshtml files are not compiled into .cs file.

Comment: It should get them as a preformatted plain text. The same it does with html.

Comment: @Artyom you're right if all js and css codes inside .cshtml file. It can handle and makes a generated .cs file with all javascript and css codes but I mean if I have seperate javascript or css files how it works . After all I think razor generator creates generated .cs files for just  "cshtml" or  "vbhtml" file types.

Comment: @slnkykrn Right, it does it only for cshtml. Other files are fetched by a browser so no need to preformat them.

Comment: @Artyom I got the answer I think, thank you.